# write pyspark RDD data into Azure Table storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-table-storage, databricks

I'm having troubles trying to write some spark RDD data into Azure Table storage.

I have an rdd which is a result of an "recommendProductsForUsers(n)" operation on an ALS model (pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS).

My first approach was to map my rdd into a new one with rows as a compatible dict for being inserted into a table (I'm using azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.TableService). after the map I did a collect with the intent of getting the actual rows to be inserted (I was planning on doing batch insertion with them). Problem is, spark explodes doing so ("Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize").

After this I tried changing approach by doing inserts inside the mapping function itself. Basically inside the map, after creating the insertion compatible dict for each row, instead of returning the object as I did before, I do the insertion itself. While this doesn't make spark crash, it won't write anything and I don't understand why. If instead I try to apply the function on a single manually extracted row (take(1)[0]), it works as expected.

Am I missing something? why the same function inside a mapping is not working?

Here is the code for the map function. It basically takes a row as input, create a dict object suitable for being inserted into an Azure table row from table_service and try to insert such object into the Azure table:

`def addCreateTableRow(r, topReturned, table_service):
      try:
        resPositionCounter = 0
        obj = {}
        obj['PartitionKey'] = 'partitionKey1'
        obj['RowKey'] = dictUsInv[r[0]]
        docKeysKey = {}
        for d in docKeys:
          docKeysKey[d[configDict['docKey']]] = d
        for res in r[1]:
          try:
            art = dictDocInv[res[1]]
            if art in docKeysKey.keys():
              obj['p'+str(resPositionCounter)] = json.dumps(docKeysKey[art])
              resPositionCounter += 1
              if resPositionCounter >= topReturned:
                break
          except:
            pass
        table_service.insert_or_replace_entity(tableNameWrite,obj)
      except:
        pass`

This is the map:
`pr.map(lambda r: addCreateTableRow(r, topReturned, table_service))`
where pr is the result of `recommendProductsForUsers(n)` ALS function aforementioned

Comment: Can you show the code? Also, what are you trying to do? (Forget about RDD's)

Comment: @Prazy I edited my op inserting code.
I'm trying to write a row into an Azure table inside a function which is used as map for each rdd row.

What do you mean with "forget about RDD"? Do you imply I should use Dataframe instead?

Comment: Are you trying to write a row to the table?

Comment: @Prazy Yes, the map function try to write a row. So by calling map on the rdd I'm trying to write multiple rows at the same time

Comment: Are you sure rdd writes it to the row?

Comment: @Prazy what do you mean? the function addCreateTableRow itself writes the input on the table. I tried by extracting a single row from rdd like this
```r = pr.take(1)[0]``` and calling ```addCreateTableRow(r, topReturned, table_service)``` and seeing that the row is properly inserted into the azure table. But if I do the ```pr.map``` on the rdd as in the snipped I inserted in op, it won't write anything in the table

Comment: Ah - now I get it. Can you add in `recommendProductsForUsers(n)` method?

Comment: @Prazy That's a spark function for MF models:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=recommendproductsforusers#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.recommendProductsForUsers

So basically I trained a model like this:
```model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings=ratings, rank=rank, iterations=iterations, lambda_=lambda_, nonnegative=True, seed=seed)```
(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS)

and then got the predictions using
```pr = model.recommendProductsForUsers(n_docs)```

Comment: Can you try to do `pr.take(1)[0]` and ` pr.collect()`? Just try to paste the OP here.

Comment: @Prazy They both work. pr.take(1)[0] returns something like this:
```(0,
 (Rating(user=0, product=6, rating=0.9984),
  Rating(user=0, product=23, rating=1.4209317533648998e-07),
  ...
  Rating(user=0, product=36, rating=0.0)))```
while the collect is just a list like this:
```
[(0,
  (Rating(user=0, product=6, rating=0.9984),
   Rating(user=0, product=23, rating=1.4209317533648998e-07),
   ...
   Rating(user=0, product=36, rating=0.0))),
 (1,
  (Rating(user=1, product=18, rating=0.9552438112361687),
  ...
   Rating(user=1, product=26, rating=0.0))
 )
 ...
 ]```

Comment: Did you try setting up `"spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g"`? Any time?

Comment: @Prazy: for the first approach, I tried setting spark.driver.maxResultSize to 12g and it still didn't work

Comment: What is your cluster memory? And, how much memory you have assigned for the driver?

Comment: @Prazy I'm using 2 workers of databricks F16s v2 tier, with 16 vCPU and 32.00 GiB RAM. The driver is the same as the workers

Comment: So you don't have this error anymore: **Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize** but, you see no data in the table, right?

Comment: @Prazy Exactly. I tried changing approach, since production data will be very variable and I didn't feel confident by using a prefixed maxResultSize

Comment: It will work the same. [0] just takes the first element of the list. 
pr.take(2) is a list of 2 elements, while pr.take(1) is a list of a single element

Comment: Create a temp rdd like this and do a collect() on it. temp = pr.map(lambda r: addCreateTableRow(r, topReturned, table_service)) temp.take(1)

Comment: Since the function ```addCreateTableRow``` doesn't return, ```temp.take(1)``` gives me ```[None]```

Comment: When you do lambda `pr.map(lambda r: addCreateTableRow(r, topReturned, table_service))`, why are you not passing any collect to 'r'?